# Tradeoffs for using soft permutations in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am exploring using soft permutations in my build of GWT because total file system size of the compiled app is important to me (read: sum of all permutations). Aside from increasing the file size the user has to download and potential runtime performance decreases, is there any other drawbacks to using soft permutations? Any loss of localization functionality (number formatting and the like)?

For clarification, [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations) is what I am calling soft permutations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are others, except that there might be incompatibilities with existing generators/linkers (I recently proposed a patch to GWT using soft permutations and it got rolled back at least twice, before being revisited with a runtime check but no soft permutation).
See [commits r9970 through r10257](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/list?path=/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/animation/client/Animation.java).

Comment: Interesting, so generators/linkers work of the optimized code? Not the original source?

Comment: After reading the wiki, generators are probably not the issue. Linkers run after everything has been compiled into JS, to somehow "assemble" the JS and put it into the appropriate `*.cache.*` files and emit the `*.nocache.js` file. I think it has to do with complicated setups within Google, and in most case it'll be OK, but still, it can happen.